# Does declaring C++ variables const help or hurt performance?

Tags: c++, performance, constants

I understand the behavior of `const`-qualified data types. I am curious, though, if there is any performance gain or loss from over- or under-zealousness of qualifying variables as `const`. I am thinking particularly of variables declared and used exclusively within an isolated code block. For example, something like:

```
const qreal padding = CalculatePadding();
const QSizeF page_size = CalculatePagePreviewSize(padding);
const QRectF content_rect = CalculatePagePreviewContentRect(page_size);
const QList<QRectF> pages = renderer.BuildPrintPages(printer_, map_scene_);
const QFont page_number_font = CalculatePageNumberFont();
const QFontMetrics metrics(page_number_font);
```

Suppose I only need `const`-qualified methods on all of these (and more.) Is there any performance gain in declaring them all `const`? Or, conversely, does this actually hurt performance?

I am curious for both run-time performance (*I am guessing this makes no difference as the `const` is exclusively a compile-time check--can someone confirm?*) and compile-time performance. I do not have enough experience with c++ to have a feel for this, and am wondering if I should err on the side of over- or under-applying `const` when all other things (maintainability, etc.) are equal.

Comment: in most cases, no run-time performance difference

Comment: Qt is much copy-on-write so I suspect const can have a real effect here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`const` is mainly a compile-time thing, however, declaring something as `const` sometimes allows for certain optimizations. If the code in question isn't a performance bottleneck, I wouldn't worry about it and just use `const` as intended: to produce clearer code and prevent yourself from doing stupid things.

Answer (score 4):

In my (limited) experience, const CAN hurt the performance by quite a lot (surprise!)
Namely, when working with container classes be careful what cont-ness does: for arrays it might simply force the compiler to create a copy of your container (e.g., an array) once a single element is accessed for reading only... This was a huge pain to locate in the code that I am working on.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that const can be used by the compiler to potentially optimize performance, but is no guarantee of such; there shouldn't be a performance downside, though. It could potentially affect runtime behavior (ie: the compiler could put const variables on read-only memory pages).

It should not have a significant impact on performance, but I'd error on using it more for ease of code maintenance. Just my opinion, though.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, `const` can improve performance *if applied to the object itself*.

**[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/q7P7MhMdq):**

```
int fmutable(void g(const int &)) {
    int x = 1;
    g(x);
    return x;  // mov rax, dword ptr [rsp + ...]
}

int fconst(void g(const int &)) {
    int const x = 1;
    g(x);
    return x;  // mov eax, 1
}
```

This happens because mutating a `const` object is illegal, so the compiler can assume you don't do that.

However, adding `const` to the target of a *reference* or *pointer* that was previously mutable doesn't improve performance, because casting away `const` and then mutating an object that wasn't originally `const` is legal, and the compiler cannot assume you don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer is technically "yes", the practical answer is NO. It's true that the compiler can, under certain circumstances, perform code optimizations by taking into account that a given value cannot change or that a method will not modify the owning object. However, these will be situational cases and so incredibly far down in the weeds of optimization that it would almost certainly be a mistake to take it into account up front.

Answer (score 0):

`const` is just there to help you catch errors at compile time.  However since there's this thing called the `const_cast` you can always change the constness of any variable so the compiler really can't get away with optimizing anything away.  (You can also have fun with c-style casts to get rid of constness which could make optimizations invalid.)

Comment: avoid `const_cast` at all times, and use it only when you have no choice (eg: you're working with an external lib you can't change the interface of, but know modifying a const object is "safe enough").

Comment: This is not really true. If you defined a variable as const, you cannot cast that away *and* write to it. A compiler that caches a variable value based on the fact that the variable is const is alright. Any program that writes to a const variable has undefined behavior.

Comment: Johannes - first result from a google search on const and optimization:  http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm  - try it yourself, you can write to an unconstified variable

Comment: The link you referred to is a different situation, where you get a constant reference to a possibly not constant object. Johannes refers to the situation where the original variable is declared as `const type name`, and modifying `name` there is undefined behavior. Consider for example, that a conforming compiler could decide to place that variable in ROM instead of regular memory, or in a read-only memory page. In both cases, trying to modify the variable could fail silently or crash the application.

Comment: i.e. If you add const-ness to a non-const object by binding it to a constant reference, you cast away the const-ness and modify it, that is ok. But you cannot cast away the const-ness of an object that **is** const.